# UILongPressGestureRecognizer not running function

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uilongpressgesturerecogni

within my viewdidload() I initialized the longpressgesturerecognizer like so

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let lpgr = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "action:")

    lpgr.minimumPressDuration = 2.0

    Capture.addGestureRecognizer(lpgr)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

And then I attempted to run this function which will later become a record button for a camera

```
func action(gestureRecognizer:UIGestureRecognizer) {
    print("pressed")

}
@IBOutlet weak var Capture: UIProgressView!
```

Comment: what happens if you change the `UIGestureRecognizer` parameter to `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`?

Comment: make sure that `Capture.view.userInteractionEnabled = true`

Comment: @DanielKrom thank you that helped it pointed out I had accidentally linked the wrong item to my view